# Building a library across platforms without running all of the platforms

Tags: c++, build, cross-platform, makefile

I have a small piece of code that works as a plugin for a larger graphics application.  The development platform is Qt with c++ code.  I've managed to build a .so, .dylib and .dll for linux, MacOS and Windows respectively, but to do so I had to have a machine running each operating system (in my case, running linux [ubuntu] gcc natively, and windows MinGW and MacOS XCode gcc in virtual machines).

Is there a way to build for all 3 platforms from one?  I beat my head against this problem a while back, and research to date suggests that it's not easily (or feasibly) done.  The code only needs to link against a single header that defines the plugin 
API and is built from a fairly basic Makefile (currently with small variations per platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never, I just came across [IMCROSS](http://www.sandroid.org/imcross/)

It looks quite promising!

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at crosscompiling.

You basically build a compiler that (on your current plattform) will output binaries for your desired platforms.

Try [this link](http://silmor.de/29) about doing it on linux, for windows, with QT

Answer (score 0):

For Linux it is fairly easy to setup or even download a virtual machine using VMWare for instance. Getting OSX to run on VMWare is somewhat tricky but possible.

Running VMWare and sharing a directory on a local drive you can even compile for the different platforms using the same exact files.

There is somewhere a cross-compiler for OSX but I wouldn't trust it to be of great quality.

Comment: OSX uses gcc, using a crosscompiler on linux to compile for OSX should get you pretty much the same thing.